# How to get data after 10 data skip in Realtime database firebase javascript node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Node js with `Express.js` and I am getting data from firebase's real-time database
so How can I get data after 10 children or nodes by skipping?

#### example

I have a lot of data like -

```
Images
     imageId
            - {some properties ie: imgUrl:"somevalue.jpg"}
     and more
```

So first I am taking **first 10 images** using `limitFirst(10)` function.

and if the user clicks on `link or next button` I want to load the next first 10 images if available

does firebase real-time database have some functionality like this

```
//limitToAfter(afterChild, limit);
const imageRef = query("Images", limitToAfter(10,10));
onValue(imageRef,(snapshot)=>{
   //some operation here...
});
```

Or can anyone give me some ways I can solve this problem?

I will always appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't have an offset mechanism. Instead to get the next page of data, you need to know the last node on the current page.

For example, say that the key of the last item on page 1 is "key10", then you can get the next 10 items with:

```
query("Images", orderByKey(), startAfter("key10"), limitToFirst(10));
```

In words: take all nodes under `Images`, order them by their key, then start after "key10" and return the first 10 nodes.

Comment: My keys are unordered means my keys are randomly unique id generated can I still use this?

Comment: Yup. You just have to pass the correct key value to `startAfter`. Give it a try. 